# Pronunciation of word ending with z sound followed by word starting with sh sound

Tags: pronunciation

Here are two examples of words ending in a *z* sound followed by a word starting with a *sh* sound:

> - Doe**s sh**e
> - Alway**s sh**ines.

Do we pronounce the *z* sound or do we skip it and pronounce *sh* directly?

Comment: I tried to make the post clearer by including the title in the body of the post. I also changed the formatting a bit. See the [Contributor's Guide (Asking)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/36187) and 
[Contributor's Guide (Formatting)](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4799/36187) for tips and examples.

Answer (score 1):

For both of these examples, the /z/ sound is still pronounced even when the following word starts with the "sh" sound.

English doesn't generally have strong sound changes across word-boundaries, except in more informal or quicker spoken forms.